# How to make the contents of a div not wrap?

Tags: html, css

I've create an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvFxl) on codepen.io of the following markup:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Inner 1</div>
  <div class="inner">Inner 2</div>
  <div class="inner">Inner 3</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.outer {
  border: 1pt solid black;
  width:320pt;
  height: 220pt;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

.inner {
  border: 1pt solid blue;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200pt;
  height: 200pt;
  background: silver;  
}
```

But my goal is to create a sort of carousel where the contents of the outer div do not wrap.  How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the outer div to prevent wrapping. Additionally, add `overflow: hidden` to hide the scrollbar.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wciLg

For a carousel, you might want to add an extra container div that contains all the elements. You can then scroll the carousel by setting `left` or `margin-left` on the inner container. But those are just my thoughts, you might have a better idea.

Comment: I had to change flex-wrap to white-space and it started working.  Perhaps "carousel" was a bad choice of words as I want the horizontal scroll bar.  Thank you for the quick and accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could add in an extra div and move that instead. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvFxl

```
   .innercontainer{  width:620pt; }
```